# plot N planes parallel to XZ axis in 3D in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot N planes (say 10) parallel to XZ axis and equidistant to each other using python. If possible it would be nice to select the number of planes from user. It will be like, if user gives "20" then 20 planes will be drawn in 3D. This is what I did.But I would like to know is there a method to call each plane or like to get each plane's equation ??

```
 import numpy as np
 import itertools
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

 plt3d = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
 xx, zz = np.meshgrid(range(10), range(10))
 yy =0.5
 for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 20):

     plt3d.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz)
     plt.hold(True)
     yy=yy+.1

     plt.show()
```

Comment: Where is *your code*? :)

Comment: I used itertools to generate surface  N times, with y value changed each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example how to implement what you need in a very generic way.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from pylab import meshgrid,linspace,zeros,dot,norm,cross,vstack,array,matrix,sqrt



def rotmatrix(axis,costheta):
    """ Calculate rotation matrix

    Arguments:
    - `axis`     : Rotation axis
    - `costheta` : Rotation angle
    """
    x,y,z = axis
    c = costheta
    s = sqrt(1-c*c)
    C = 1-c
    return  matrix([[ x*x*C+c,    x*y*C-z*s,  x*z*C+y*s ],
                    [ y*x*C+z*s,  y*y*C+c,    y*z*C-x*s ],
                    [ z*x*C-y*s,  z*y*C+x*s,  z*z*C+c   ]])

def plane(Lx,Ly,Nx,Ny,n,d):
    """ Calculate points of a generic plane 

    Arguments:
    - `Lx` : Plane Length first direction
    - `Ly` : Plane Length second direction
    - `Nx` : Number of points, first direction
    - `Ny` : Number of points, second direction
    - `n`  : Plane orientation, normal vector
    - `d`  : distance from the origin
    """

    x = linspace(-Lx/2,Lx/2,Nx)
    y = linspace(-Ly/2,Ly/2,Ny)
    # Create the mesh grid, of a XY plane sitting on the orgin
    X,Y = meshgrid(x,y)
    Z   = zeros([Nx,Ny])
    n0 = array([0,0,1])

    # Rotate plane to the given normal vector
    if any(n0!=n):
        costheta = dot(n0,n)/(norm(n0)*norm(n))
        axis     = cross(n0,n)/norm(cross(n0,n))
        rotMatrix = rotmatrix(axis,costheta)
        XYZ = vstack([X.flatten(),Y.flatten(),Z.flatten()])
        X,Y,Z = array(rotMatrix*XYZ).reshape(3,Nx,Ny)

    dVec = (n/norm(n))*d
    X,Y,Z = X+dVec[0],Y+dVec[1],Z+dVec[2]
    return X,Y,Z


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Plot as many planes as you like
    Nplanes = 10

    # Set color list from a cmap
    colorList = cm.jet(linspace(0,1,Nplanes))

    # List of Distances
    distList = linspace(-10,10,Nplanes)

    # Plane orientation - normal vector
    normalVector = array([0,1,1]) # Y direction

    # Create figure
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    # Plotting
    for i,ypos in enumerate(linspace(-10,10,10)):

        # Calculate plane
        X,Y,Z = plane(20,20,100,100,normalVector,distList[i])

        ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=5, cstride=5,
                        alpha=0.8, color=colorList[i])

    # Set plot display parameters    
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_xlim(-10, 10)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    ax.set_zlim(-10, 10)

    plt.show()
```

[image]

If you need to rotate the plane around the normal vector, you can also use the rotation matrix for that.

Cheers

Comment: Is it possible to get equation of each these plane separately ??

Comment: Now you have a function that calculates the points of a generic plane. You can even use any plane orientation you like. If you want to get the equation of the planes you can use the points of the planes and use the concepts described in this wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)